# the visual studio gives E0028

Tags: c++

I have a problem , the visual studio gives me error E0028 (the expression must have a constant value) in 40 line, the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void start(int i, int number_of_test, int numtodo, int numwas)
{
    for (int i = numwas; i < numtodo; i++)
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
            else if (i == j + 1)
                cout << i << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int threads;
    cout << "threads";
    cin >> threads;
    int number;
    cout << "number";
    cin >> number;
    int number_of_test = 0;
    int numtodo = 0;
    int numwas = 0;
    while (i < threads + 1)
    {
        if (i < threads + 1) {


            i = i + 1;
            number_of_test = number / threads;
            numtodo = number_of_test * i;
            numwas = numtodo / number_of_test;
            thread t[i](start, int(i), number_of_test, numtodo, numwas);
            t[i].join();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do threads in loop, for example not to write 128 threads, just to run the loop and it run a lot of threads. line 40 :thread t[i](start, int(i), number_of_test, numtodo, numwas); , error in t[I], I need to fix it , but I don't know how , I need to do a lot of threads (like t1, than t2 etc..)

Comment: What is error E0028? [Edit] the question to include the full text of the error message, including any informational lines.

Comment: Also, what is line 40?

Comment: What is `thread t[i](start, int(i), number_of_test, numtodo, numwas);` supposed to do? Probably that's the error. That's a strange mix of constructor call and array access.

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: The whole threading part seems pointless since you just `join()` the thread when you've started it. Btw, if someone enters a `number` that is less than `threads` then `number_of_test` will be `0` and you'll get a division by zero later.

Comment: It just not starting , after i will fix it , idk how to fix e0028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does not make sense (and may be the cause for the problem):

```
thread t[i](start, int(i), number_of_test, numtodo, numwas);
```

You should create an array or vector to store the thread objects. Example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//void start(...

int main() {  
    std::cout << "threads: ";

    size_t threads;
    std::cin >> threads;
    std::vector<std::thread> t(threads); // create a vector to hold the thread objects

    int number;
    std::cout << "number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    if (number < t.size()) return 1;

    int number_of_test = 0;
    int numtodo = 0;
    int numwas = 0;

    // start all threads
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); ++i)
    {
        number_of_test = number / t.size();
        numtodo = number_of_test * (i+1);
        numwas = numtodo / number_of_test;

        // start one thread and store it in its place in the vector:
        t[i] = std::thread(start, i, number_of_test, numtodo, numwas);
    }

    // join all threads
    for (auto& th : t) th.join();
}
```